# How can I sort a XAML gridview in a Windows 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have the following xaml code about GridView:

```
<GridView x:Name="ivGridView" Margin="70,40,10,10" SelectionChanged="ivGridView_SelectionChanged">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="{Binding Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Foreground="White" Margin="7,0,0,0" FontWeight="Light" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

How do I implement the sort for the GridView based on the Textblock value which binds to name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the associated ItemsSource to sort the items in the view.

```
 public ObservableCollection<Test> TestOC = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    TestOC.Add(new Test() {name="BBB",id="1",Color=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)});
    TestOC.Add(new Test() { name = "CCC", id="11", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) });
    TestOC.Add(new Test() {  name = "AA", id="111", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange) });
    var SortResult = TestOC.OrderBy(a => a.name);           
    ivGridView.ItemsSource =SortResult;
}
```